# Pandas: Create column in dataframe and assign value to the column by looking into another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two dataframe as below.

DF1 and DF2

[image]

[image]

I want to create a column in DF1 as "name" and assign value based on below condition.

```
1) Check if DF1['C1'] value is available in DF2['C']
2) If yes, assign DF1['name'] with the value in DF2['name']
3) If no, Check if DF1['C2'] value is available in DF2['C']
4) If yes, assign DF1['name'] with the value in DF2['name']
5) If both DF1['C1'] value is not found in DF2['C'] then assign DF1['name'] as other.
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` each column with the second DataFrame and use `combine_first` to deal with your priority logic. Then fill any missing values to get `'other'`

```
s = df2.set_index('C')['name']
df1['name'] = df1['C1'].map(s).combine_first(df1['C2'].map(s)).fillna('other')

   C1  C2   name
0   0   1      x
1   6   4      z
2   7   5  other
```

Answer (score 0):

first merge `df1` with `df2` on `c1`. Separately merge `df1` with `df2` on `c2`. Fill `na` in first df with second.

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [0, 6, 7], 'c2': [1, 4, 5]})
>>> df1
   c1  c2
0   0   1
1   6   4
2   7   5

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c': [0, 1, 4], 'name': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
>>> df2
   c name
0  0    x
1  1    y
2  4    z

>>> df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on="c1", right_on="c", how="left").drop("c",axis=1)
>>> df3
   c1  c2 name
0   0   1    x
1   6   4  NaN
2   7   5  NaN

>>> df4 = df1.merge(df2, left_on="c2", right_on="c", how="left").drop("c",axis=1)
>>> df4
   c1  c2 name
0   0   1    y
1   6   4    z
2   7   5  NaN

>>> df3["name"].fillna(df4["name"], inplace=True)
>>> df3
   c1  c2 name
0   0   1    x
1   6   4    z
2   7   5  NaN

>>> df3.fillna("other", inplace=True)
>>> df3
   c1  c2   name
0   0   1      x
1   6   4      z
2   7   5  other
```